# Store datagridview into datarow

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, datatable

I want to store the values the values held in a **DatagridView** and store them in a **DataTable**. I am using the following code but what I am doing wrong as it is not moving it to the **DataTable**?

```
   Dim dt As New DataTable, ds As New DataSet

        Dim updatelist As String = String.Empty
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvSteak.Rows.Count - 1
            updatelist = dgvSteak.CurrentRow.Index


            Dim newSteakRow As DataRow = ds.Tables("Steak").NewRow()

            newSteakRow("STEAK_ID") = dgvSteak.Item("Steak_ID", i).Value
            newSteakRow("STEAK_Name") = dgvSteak.Item("Steak_Name", i).Value

            ds.Tables("Steak").Rows.Add(newSteakRow)

        Next
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: I am using the following code but what I am doing wrong as it is not moving it to the DataTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use to copy a datagridview to a datatable and it seems to work. So datatable row 2, columns 4 will have the same value as datagridview row 2, columns 4, and so on.

```
    Dim datatable1 As New DataTable
    Dim a, b As Integer

    ' make the datatable rows and columns match the datagridview
    a = 0
    Do While a < Me.DataGridView1.ColumnCount
        datatable1.Columns.Add()
        a += 1
    Loop
    a = 0
    Do While a < Me.DataGridView1.RowCount
        datatable1.Rows.Add()
        a += 1
    Loop

    ' add datagridview values to datatable
    a = 0
    Do While a < Me.DataGridView1.ColumnCount
        b = 0
        Do While b < Me.DataGridView1.RowCount
            datatable1.Rows(a).item(b) = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(a).cells(b).value
            b += 1
        Loop
        a += 1
    Loop
```

Comment: To include the headers into your datatable change datatable1.Columns.Add() to datatable1.Columns.Add(Me.DataGridView1.Columns(a).HeaderText)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim dt As New DataTable()

        For c As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn() {New DataColumn(DataGridView1.Columns(c).HeaderText, GetType(String))})
        Next

        For r As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            dt.Rows.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(r))
        Next

        For c As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            For r As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                dt.Rows(r).Item(c) = DataGridView1.Rows(r).Cells(c).Value.ToString
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: Your use of for/next looks better than the other answer. However, I don't think you can do `dt.Rows.Add(DateGridView1.Rows(r))` because `DataGridView1.Rows(r)` is a `DataGridViewRow` but `DataRow.Add(row)` only accepts a row of type `DataRow`. I think you will get an exception if you try to pass a `DataGridViewRow` instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).